# C++ Static type checking (BOOST) incorrectly flagged by Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, eclipse-cdt, static-assert

So, I want to use the BOOST libraries to static-time check that my templates are being used by certain base classes, for example:

```
template <class T>
class A {
    // Code here
}
```

So, I wanted to use `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( ( boost::is_base_of<DesiredBaseClass, T>::value ) )`, and this works great with GCC. However, Eclipse is being very annoying with this, and it listing errors (from its own parsers methinks).

The errors are:

```
Type 'T' could not be resolved  (Code Analysis Problem)
Type 'DesiredBaseClass' could not be resolved   (Code Analysis Problem)
Symbol 'value' could not be resolved    (Semantic Error)
```

Does anyone know a good work around to stop Eclipse complaining? I could turn off its parser, but I think its generally pretty good at picking up problems.

Comment: How about an example where we can see what `DesiredBaseClass` and `T` are and the context of the `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I updated Eclipse CDT to the latest version and the problem's disappeared.

Seems the parser or whatever was generating the warning has been updated to fix the problem. Apologies for not thinking to try and before.